# cp: No such file or directory when copying phpMyAdmin folder to /Library/WebServer/Documents/

Tags: php, macos, terminal, cp

When I use the following command:

```
 ~/Downloads  cp -r phpMyAdmin /Library/WebServer/Documents/
```

I get this error:

```
cp: /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpMyAdmin/sql/upgrade_tables_4_7_0+.sql: No such file or directory

for all the files
```

.

How should I fix this in OSX?

I have

```
ls -l /Library/WebServer/Documents/                                                                                                           1 ✘  at 01:38:03 AM 
total 80
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   3726 Aug 29  2019 PoweredByMacOSX.gif
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  31958 Aug 29  2019 PoweredByMacOSXLarge.gif
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     45 Aug 29  2019 index.html.en
```

and also 755 on phpMyAdmin folder in Downloads folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to copy it with `sudo`, as the owner seems to be `root:wheel`:

```
sudo cp -r ./phpMyAdmin /Library/WebServer/phpMyAdmin
```